# How can I delete empty space at the bottom of my table?

Tags: html

I am trying to figure out why is there empty space at the bottom of my table?  How can I delete that space?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#CDD2FF">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:bottom">

      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="x.php">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="x.php">Item</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="x.php">Item</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space ie because of the default margin allocated for the UL element.
Try setting the margin-bottom to 0; i.e.:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#CDD2FF">
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:bottom">
        <ul style="margin-bottom: 0">
          <li><a href="x.php">Item</a></li>

          <li><a href="x.php">Item</a></li>

          <li><a href="x.php">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```